# Ion-select não funciona como deveria

Tags: ionic, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Tenho o seguinte código para o ion-select:

```
<ion-item class="drop-categoria" style="margin-bottom: 5%; ">
  <ion-label>Categorias</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="catselected" (ng-change)="onChange(catselected)">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let cat of categorias" [value]="cat.nome" >{{ cat.nome }}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

E no .ts:

```
  onChange(catselected){
    console.log(catselected);

    }
```

Eu preciso pegar o valor selecionado, no caso o `cat.nome`, porém quando eu clicko em OK, nada ocorre, nenhum erro, e nenhuma resposta, oque pode ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra min funcionou da seguinte maneira:

```
<ion-item class="drop-categoria" style="margin-bottom: 5%; ">
  <ion-label>Categorias</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="cati" (ionChange)="onChange(cati);">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let cat of categorias" [value]="cat.nome" >{{ cat.nome }}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

e no .ts

```
  onChange(){
    console.log(this.cati);

    }
```

Comment: essa forma funcionou muito bem aqui pra mim, obrigado!